# TempData and ViewData die pretty quickly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, tempdata

Is there a way that I can store variables for long periods of time?  My users will be leaving their windows open for extended periods of time (Up to a couple (3) of hours).  If they do that, then there is a chance that the values will become null. If am correct, `ViewData` goes null as soon as the view is loaded.  What would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use [Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx). Or, if your users are authenticating somehow, persist the information relative to the account in a database somewhere.

If you want to use session, you can use something like this in a controller's action method:

```
Session["Key"] = somevalue;
```

Now, session state dies eventually as well, such as when the user closes their browser, or has been inactive for a while. The default is 20 minutes. If you want to change this, modify the `timeout` attribute under the [`sessionState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9.aspx) configuration element of your web.config.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea that I might give a try.  I know all of this is so very un RESTfull.  Oh well.